# how can i get child struct name in parent func?

Tags: go

how can i get child struct name in parent func? my online code is here:
[`https://go.dev/play/p/04w5mK0aAgL`](https://go.dev/play/p/04w5mK0aAgL)

```golang
type IParent interface {
    TypeName() string
}

type Parent struct{ IParent }

func (p *Parent) TypeName() string {

    if t := reflect.TypeOf(p); t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        return "*" + t.Elem().Name()
    } else {
        return t.Name()
    }
}

type Child struct {
    *Parent
}

func main() {
    var e IParent = &Child{}

    // output: TypeName: *Parent.
    // expected: TypeName: *Child.
    val := e.TypeName()
    fmt.Printf("TypeName: %v.\n", val)
}
```

the output is `TypeName: *Parent.`, my expected output is `TypeName: *Child.`, could someone can give me some suggest?

Comment: You can't. The `p` inside `TypeName()` will always be of type `*Parent`, no matter how many times you embed it in another struct. Go does not have support for inheritance, so you need to stop thinking in that paradigm. `Child` does NOT inherit from `*Parent`, what you have there is *composition*, i.e. `Child` *embeds* `*Parent`, in other words `Child` "contains" `*Parent`.

Comment: `e.TypeName()` is a valid expression ONLY because the methods and fields of **embedded** fields (fields with only type and no name), are **promoted** to the embedding struct. And "promoted" methods and fields can be accessed directly, but they are still part and parcel of the embedded field, they are not part of the embedding struct. Basically `e.TypeName()` is in reality `e.Parent.TypeName()`.

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/faq#inheritance

Comment: got.it! it seems golang did not have oop.

Comment: The name of the language is Go. Go is object oriented even without inheritance. Take the Tour of Go for fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

I think u miss with the concept of struct in go.

```
type Child struct {
    *Parent
}

func main() {
    var e IParent = &Child{}
```

Above, clearly if u define the struct Child with Parent as the content of struct, but afterthat u declare the child and output the content. In here so clearly the result is *Parent.